# Ubuntu 20.04 "show applications" button does not work

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and the *Show Applications* button does not work. When I click it, the screen blinks once, the cursor of the mouse jumps to the lower right corner, the screen blinks a second time and that is it.

Meanwhile, I activated the Tweak option to have an old fashion Applications menu in the tile bar, but I'd rather have a solution for the *Show Applications* button.

Any hint?

---

Answering a comment about the desktop I use, when I give this command in a terminal:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

I get:

```
ubuntu:GNOME
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have installed `chrome-gnome-shell`. Open the *Gnome Shell Integration* extension on your browser, then disable the *Hide Activities Button* extension if you have installed it.